# Why does a joinable thread terminate before pthread_join?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

The documentation for the pthread_join function says:

> Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is
> not detached), produces a "zombie thread".

As far as I understand this statement, after the thread terminates, it remains a zombie until we call pthred_join. However, I wrote a program and it turned out that the completed joinable thread is completely terminated after return. But how then do we get the thread exit code in pthread_join? Where is the exit code stored?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *mythread(void *arg)
{
    printf("mythread [%d %d %d]: Hello from mythread!\n", getpid(), getppid(), gettid());
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int));
     *result = 42;
     return result;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid;
    int err;

    printf("main [%d %d %d]: Hello from main!\n", getpid(), getppid(), gettid());

    err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, mythread, NULL);
    if (err) {
        printf("main: pthread_create() failed: %s\n", strerror(err));
        return -1;
    }

    sleep(1000);

    void *thread_result;

    if (pthread_join(tid, &thread_result) != 0) {
        perror("Thread join failed");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Thread returned: %d\n", *((int *)thread_result));
    return 0;
}
```

[Launching the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8AGD.png)

[View process threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF3Xb.png)

It can be seen that in the process table there is only the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread exit code of a joinable thread that is still not joined is stored *in the zombie thread*. That's what zombie threads are, more or less: pieces of data that store thread exit codes.

Under Linux, a zombie thread is not a process (i.e. doesn't have an entry in the process table) so `ps` will not show it. `pthread_exit` calls `exit` (the system call, not the eponymous C library function) so that the process that corresponds to that thread truly terminates. There is no trace of it in the process table. However there is still a zombie thread hanging somewhere.

Comment: Interestingly, if the main thread calls pthread_exit before the others, it will still go into the zombie state.
Is this because the main thread must pass the process exit code to the parent process or why?

Comment: @helhel if the main thread calls pthread_exit, the *process* becomes a zombie until all other threads exit. It is a different state from being a zombie thread.

Comment: @helhel, you do not get what is usually called a "zombie process" until *all* the process's threads have terminated. If the initial thread of a process terminates by calling `pthread_exit()` while there are other live threads in the process, then *that thread* becomes a zombie.  It can be joined normally by any of the remaining threads.  In that case (as ever), any live thread can terminate the whole process and provide its exit status by calling `exit()`.  If all of them terminate without calling `exit()` then it is as if execution reached the closing `}` of `main()`: the exit status is 0.